# react router 4 redirect to first route when basename changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, browser-history

i'm using `BrowserRouter` for routing in react for i18n i need to set basename to `/fa/` for persian and `/` for english so i change basename dynamicly the problem is when basename changes Router path change to first route i was entered. 
for example:

i enter app with this url : `app.com/companies/` then go to `app.com/investors/` after that i change language and basename will change to `/fa/` then i will get back to `app.com/fa/companies/` instead of `app.com/fa/investors` 
This is how i set basename:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, RouteProps, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
<Router basename={this.props.language.isEnglish ? '/' : '/fa/'}>
 // Routes...
<Router />
```

so how can i prevent from redirecting to first route. ?

 is this a problem at all or this is how it should be ? 
is there better way for i18n in react router (we don't use react-intl) ?

Comment: Try putting "exact" word as follows <Router exact basename=

Comment: @VitoMadio but there is no exact Props on Router Component even in api documentation btw i tested it nothing changed at all

Comment: Ok, just a note, if you're using react v4 you should use react-router-dom instead of react-router.

Comment: @VitoMadio i'm using react-router-dom 
i added an example what happen to question

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your entire rooter pls :)

Are you using [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) ?

extract from react-training

`Switch will start looking for a matching <Route>. <Route path="/about"/> will match and <Switch> will stop looking for matches and render <About>`

So if `/fa` is needed your rooter will match this url first and then render the right component

Therefore i18n or react-intl is the same but i advice to use i18n. Because i18n is now a standard of the world wide web